# Eclipse Kepler: detached window and toolbar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

In my Eclipse plug-in I have a custom editor which has its own toolbar. If I detach such an editor I still can use this toolbar. But only if there is no other editor (without this toolbar) active on the workbench. In this case the toolbar of the detached window disappears while activating the workbench so I can't use it anymore for the detached window. Is this a bug or a feature?

Is it somehow possible to attach the toolbar to the detached editor window to prevent such errors?

Comment: This seems to work for me testing with the Java editor detached. Perhaps it the problem is how you have defined the enablement or visibility of the toolbar.

Comment: I use a content type binding. This allows to display the toolbar only for the appropriate documents. The toolbar disappears for different documents.

Answer (score 0):

If your editor's toolbar is actually showing in the main window (the usual case) then what is happening is that when you click on the main window to use the tool the main window activates, changing the currently active part. This is a known issue for which no viable solution has been proposed...

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323706 and related defects for the gory details.

The usual workaround is to use key-bindings for commands you want to execute in DW's.